# Output of a part of data from a json array

Tags: reactjs, json, typescript, redux

I'm working on a project that uses React redux typescript.
The json file has

> "data_start": "2022-09-02"

Is it possible to output it in this format ?

> (2022, 09, 02)

I'm just learning programming so I don't know how to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the desired output you could do the following:

```
`(${data_start.replaceAll('-', ', ')})`
```